# Failed Transaction on Ethereum

Tags: ethereum, solidity, go-ethereum

I've played around for some bit with a selfmade program. I just tried to sell some random token on uniswap which I bought earlier. My transaction somehow didn't go through and I don't know why.

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xcb4ef6baab722e00e6dad75d12398fc88cc5177445758064a14c8433612a860f

Does someone have an Idea why it didn't go through, I'm not familiar enough with the solidity/ethereum yet.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: End user questions are better to be asked on https://ethereum.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

We can check which require the transaction failed to meet by searching for the message in contract `TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED`.

The function calls transferFrom function. transferFrom function requires the owner of the token to approve a spender to spend on his/her behalf.

Seems like you have not approve the spender to spend on your behalf.

You can check more info regarding transferFrom at this [docs](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/token/erc20#IERC20-allowance-address-address-)

```
// bytes4(keccak256(bytes('transferFrom(address,address,uint256)')));
(bool success, bytes memory data) = token.call(abi.encodeWithSelector(0x23b872dd, from, to, value));
require(success && (data.length == 0 || abi.decode(data, (bool))), 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED');
```

`swapExactTokensForETH` uses `safeTransferFrom` function

```
...
TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom( 
   path[0], 
   msg.sender, 
   UniswapV2Library.pairFor(factory, path[0], path[1]),
    amounts[0]
);
...
```